# How to configure Magento 2 in subfolder using NGINX

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, installation, nginx

I install Magento in my root folder and it's ok, but when I install in my subfolder don't work.

How could I do it using a Magento 2 install?

Comment: Is that a Magento 2 or Magento 1 question ?

Comment: In the both versions.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 comes with a default `nginx.conf.sample` file that you can use to setup your NGINX configuration.

I suggest you use this file and take a look at the first lines of the file:

```
# Magento Vars
# set $MAGE_ROOT /path/to/magento/root;
```

You need to uncomment the second line and change that to match your Magento root folder, if Magento is installed in a subfolder, let's say `/var/www/html/magento2/magento` then you should change the code to:

```
# Magento Vars
set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/magento2/magento;
```

Comment: It does not work with my setup. This var is setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to enable the rewrite mod in your subfolder installation, paste in VHOST of the NGINX:

```
rewrite ^/YOUR_SUBPATH$ /YOUR_SUBPATH/$1 permanent;
location /YOUR_SUBPATH/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /YOUR_SUBPATH/index.php?$args;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
rewrite ^/YOUR_SUBPATH/admin$ /YOUR_SUBPATH/admin/$1 permanent;
```

Change the **YOUR_SUBPATH** to your subpath.

Change the **admin** if your admin route is customized.

Comment: make sure your other deny rules are correctly changed